# How can word "indigestion" compare to "Acute" here?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), J.J asks his press agent Sidney
about this boy Dallas who is having a affair with his sister:

> J.J: What has this boy got that Susie likes?
>
> Sidney: Integrity. **Acute, like indigestion**.

Dictionary meanings of these two words:

> indigestion - upset stomach

> acute - extremely great or serious

How can word "indigestion" compare to "Acute" here?

Comment: Both are unpleasant to experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidney does not like 'this boy' that Susie likes, and finds his integrity (or possibly an irritating display of it) annoying. So he calls it 'acute' which has both everyday and medical meanings and compares it to an upset stomach.